# read HDF file with pandas containing special characters in the index

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, hdf

How can I store data with spacial characters in the index (e.g: äüö) into a HDF file.

Create a DataFrame:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),
                      columns=['A','B','C','D'],
                      index=["a", "ä", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])

    df.to_hdf("test.h5", "data")
```

Read the data from the hdf file:

```
    store = pd.HDFStore("test.h5")
```

Missing index:

```
    In [17]: store.data
    Out[17]: 
              A         B         C         D
    a  0.859861 -1.017473 -0.095029  0.220382
       0.472394  0.658839  0.494681 -0.350250
    b  1.180679  0.513142  1.286615  0.807974
    c -0.382927  1.983893  0.553454 -0.246470
    d -1.738026  2.050707  0.820716 -0.564973
    e -0.104748  0.926204 -0.543239 -0.632866
    f  0.886118  0.948541  1.759265 -0.937207
    g -1.670633  0.069873  0.037105 -0.809620
```

Comment: What is your python version, and what is the result you get from `sys.getdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: Also what are your pandas and pytables versions?  Your code works fine for me with python 2.7 (pandas 15.2, pytables 3.1.1) but silently fails for python 3.4 with an identical output to yours . It's possible that there is a bug in pandas there.

Comment: This is related to the following issues https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7244 and https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7605 Updating to pandas 16.0 might help.

Comment: I am using pandas 0.16.0 and also have the problem.

Comment: `sys.getdefaultencoding()` --> **utf-8**
I'm usig python version **3.4.3**
and pandas version **0.15.0**

Comment: I also have `utf-8` on python 3.4.1 and pandas 0.16.0, and can reproduce the problem.